# How to stream resultsets in spring Data JPA with custom criteria

Tags: spring, hibernate, spring-data-jpa

I'm working on a POC, using Spring Boot 2.0.5, Spring Data JPA using Hibernate. I'm trying to implement a way to stream the result sets for a custom criteria. I have seen examples like

```
public interface MyRepository implements JPARepository<Person,Long>{
    @Query("select p from person p")
    Stream<Person> findAll();
}
```

However I'm extending `SimpleJPARepository` and want to get results as a stream using a `Criteria` something like

```
Stream<Person> findAll(Criteria criteria);
```

Since I'm using class that extends `SimpleJPARepository`, I need to provide my implementation. But are there any methods in `SimpleJPARepository` or its parent classes, that can provide me default implementation using the criteria I provide. Any reference to such example is much helpful.

Also, in some examples I see that `@NoRepositoryBean` is used and in some cases `@Repository`. I'm confused between these two and which one should I use and why?

Comment: Did you get a chance to look at the implementation of SimpleJPARepository here: https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-data-jpa/blob/master/src/main/java/org/springframework/data/jpa/repository/support/SimpleJpaRepository.java If you are extending the interface, you might want to use @Repository. As classes implementing the data access part are annotated as such

Comment: https://www.baeldung.com/spring-data-java-8

Answer (score -3):

As per Spring Data JPA specifications [Spring Data JPA](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/), this is how you can create Criteria queries.

Step 1:  extend your repository interface with the `JpaSpecificationExecutor` interface, as follows:

```
public interface CustomerRepository extends CrudRepository<Customer, Long>, JpaSpecificationExecutor {
 …
}
```

Step 2: the findAll method returns all entities that match the specification, as shown in the following example:

```
List<T> findAll(Specification<T> spec);
```

Step 3: The Specification interface is defined as follows:

```
public interface Specification<T> {
  Predicate toPredicate(Root<T> root, CriteriaQuery<?> query,
            CriteriaBuilder builder);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I implemented Specifications as suggested.

Comment: But I'm still not able to proceed with Streaming part. Without using @Query annotation, how can I return results as stream.

Comment: But this does not return a Stream

Comment: The question was about Stream not List